# Comparing eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I want to prove that the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
8q_1^2-4q_2&-4q_1\\-4q_1&2(1+\epsilon)
\end{pmatrix}$$ for all $q=(q_1,q_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ 
has two eigenvalues $\lambda_1(q)$ and $\lambda_2(q)$ one positive and the other negative for all $q\in\mathbb{R}^2$

Please help me to do so.
Thanks

Comment: You must have some idea of how to approach this. How do you compute eigenvalues of a $2\times2$ matrix in the first place? Simply pasting what looks like a homework problem without any of your own efforts is oe of the best ways to get your question closed.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial is a second degree polynomial that you can solve using the general formula. Check whether the discriminant is always greater than 0

Comment: I am sorry but it is not a question of discriminant, but a question of determinant of the initial matrix, because the issue of the OP is equivalent to say that the determinant (being the products of eigenvalues) is negative (which, besides, will not be always the case...)

Comment: Nevertheless, the discriminant has to be positive in order to obtain 2 real roots. The answer was meant as an indication in how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial is:   $$((8q_1^2-4q_2)-\lambda)(2(1+\epsilon) -\lambda) -16q_1^2=\lambda ^2-((8q_1^2-4q_2^2)+2(1+\epsilon))\lambda +(8q_1^2-4q_2)(2(1+\epsilon) -16q_1^2$$.

This is a quadratic polynomial with discriminant $((8q_1^2-4q_2)+2(1+\epsilon))^2-4(16q_1^2\epsilon-4q_2(2(1+\epsilon))=(8q_1^2-4q_2)^2+2(8q_1^2-4q_2)(2(1+\epsilon) +(2(1+\epsilon)) ^2 -4(16q_1\epsilon-8q_2(1+\epsilon) )=(8q_1^2-4q_2)^2+(2(1+\epsilon ))^2+32q_1^2-16q_2+4\epsilon (8q_1^2-4q_2)-64q_1\epsilon +32q_2(1+\epsilon) =(8q_1^2-4q_2)^2+4(1+\epsilon) ^2+32(1+\epsilon) q_1^2+16(1+\epsilon) q_2-64q_1\epsilon$.

This will be positive if $q=(q_1,q_2)$ is in the second quadrant...  in which case we get two distinct real eigenvalues...

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=d94e49734c721cd23b80f90ae40520d5&title=Eigenvalue%20Calculator(2x2)&theme=blue&i0=8q_1%5E2-4q_2%20&i1=-4q_1%20&i2=-4q_1%20&i3=2(1%2B%5Cepsilon)%20&podSelect=&includepodid=Input&includepodid=Result&includepodid=CorrespondingEigenvalue%2Feigenvector&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1) are expressions for the eigenvalues using Wolfram's eigenvalue calculator...

Comment: the discriminant is only positive in the second quadran?

Comment: I get that it is positive there.  Not sure about elsewhere...

Comment: ok in second quadran, do we have an eigenvalue which is positive an the other one is negative?

Comment: In the second quadrant,  one will be larger than the other, since they will both be real.  That's all I can see...